# set comprehension vs. nested loop

Tags: python, set-comprehension

I have a list of strings, each having one or more words. I need to make a list of unique words out of this list. I can do it easily with two nested loops but I don't understand why I don't get the same result using a set comprehension.

Nested loop:

```
import re

items = ['17th C White', 'Accra White', 'Acid White']

word_list = set()
for item in items:
    for word in re.split("\s|[-'/]", item):
        word_list.add(word)
print(word_list)
```

Result from the nested loop (correct):

```
{'White', 'Acid', 'Accra', '17th', 'C'}
```

Set comprehension:

```
import re

items = ['17th C White', 'Accra White', 'Acid White']

word_list = {word for word in re.split("\s|[-'/]", item) for item in items}
print(word_list)
```

Result from the set comprehension (incorrect):

```
{'White', 'Acid'}
```

Why I don't get the same result from the set comprehension?

Comment: Not an answer, but a smaller alternative: `set(' '.join(items).split(' '))`, or with regex `set(re.split("[\s-'/]", ' '.join(items)))`

Answer (score 1):

Your set comprehension is not quite right.

You have:

```
{word for word in re.split("\s|[-'/]", item) for item in items}
```

You mean:

```
{word for item in items for word in re.split("\s|[-'/]", item)}
```

The first version is using the previous value of `item`, which must be `"Acid White"`, in the expression `for word in re.split("\s|[-'/]", item)`.

Where you have multiple `for` parts in one comprehension, you should place the one defining a variable (`item`), before the one using the variable (`re.split("\s|[-'/]", item)`).

Comment: Thanks! Now, I better understand the logic. It seems I need some more practice before Python becomes like my native language.